# presenting a table row in a list

Tags: tables, lists, reports

Is there any best practice for converting a row in a table to a list?

I want to show a report for a single row in a table, since the row is very wide, and I only want to report a single line at each report, I think a list is the best way to display it, Is there any best practice for converting a row in a table to a list?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "convert"? Any chance you could share what you have in an image?

Comment: @Alvaro I have updated the question for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see a list as a simplified table:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The only thing to note from your example, to make the "conversion" from table to list clearer, is to **include "row1" in the table**. Notice how in the example above I included an extra column that is the same as your "row1" (UserA, UserB). For this column I didn't include a header, precisely to denote that this is the header or main element of the row and that it's value can't appear twice.